# Parse string based on type

Tags: java, string, parsing

I've seen some answer that are close to what Im looking for but they dont work.

So i have a lot of settings of different types and was wondering if I could parse the string value of them in 2 lines of code instead of doing it seperate for each.
The settings look like this

```
    public static Setting<Boolean> e = new BooleanSetting("name",true);
    public static Setting<Integer> num = new IntegerSetting("number",1);
```

To parse it right now I check for the type, so for boolean and int it would look like

```
if(setting instanceof BooleanSetting) {
    setting.value=Boolean.parseBoolean(astring[1]);
}
if(setting instanceof IntegerSetting) {
    setting.value=Integer.parseInt(astring[1]);
}
```

But since I know the type of setting it is, is there any way I can do something like

```
setting.value=setting.type.parseType(astring[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why and where you check the `instanceof` stuff.

`BooleanSetting` and `IntegerSetting` are implementations or subclasses of `Setting<T>`. They know what their `T` is.

`Setting` should have an `abstract T parseValue(String s)` in which every subclass or implementation decides how to parse that `String`.

For instance:

```
class BooleanSetting extends Setting<Boolean> { //or implements
  @Override
  Boolean parseValue(String s) {
    return Boolean.parseBoolean(s);
  }
}
```

This moves all type-specific parsing to the subclass.

Comment: Im trying to make the value to be the correct type so im parsing the string value I store in a file to the value of the correct type

Comment: This is only happening one time, so I dont think a method is necessary. I want something in java just to be used once. But thanks that is some good code